# Ojdbc6.jar error while using oracle spatial

Tags: spring, oracle, tomcat6, mybatis, oracle-spatial

I'm getting strange error while using ojdbc6.jar with spatial data. Stack trace says class definition not found XMLType. But xdb6.jar is required only in case of xml to db. However I'm not dealing with xml to db stuff anywhere in code. Here is the stack trace. could you please give me insight, oneway is to copy the xdb6.jar but I do not want copy that file since I'm not using xml to db

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: oracle/xdb/XMLType

```
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162) ~[cxf-api-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:213) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128) ~[cxf-api-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:68) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75) ~[cxf-api-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) ~[cxf-api-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]

    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) ~[cxf-api-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107) ~[cxf-api-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271) ~[cxf-api-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:203) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) [tomcat6-servlet-2.5-api-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.24.jar:na]

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xdb/XMLType

```
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getString(NamedTypeAccessor.java:355) ~[tomcat6/:na]

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getString(GeneratedStatement.java:327) ~[tomcat6/:na]

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getString(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:882) ~[tomcat6/:na]

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:213) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:213) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]

    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.ResultSetLogger.printColumnValues(ResultSetLogger.java:84) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.ResultSetLogger.invoke(ResultSetLogger.java:56) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at $Proxy54.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.shouldProcessMoreRows(FastResultSetHandler.java:221) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(FastResultSetHandler.java:212) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(FastResultSetHandler.java:186) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(FastResultSetHandler.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:57) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:70) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:57) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:101) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:95) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_09-icedtea]

    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:355) ~[mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]

    at $Proxy58.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:195) ~[mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:124) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:90) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

    at $Proxy59.getBeamScallopingData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short story: You're going to need to include the XDB library.

Long story: If you dig into it, you'll find that the cause of the NoClassDefFoundError is that one of the classes you're using (either your direct use or indirectly) will reference the XMLType class.

Even if you're not using XMLType, the class must be present on the classpath for the class you actually are using to be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was hoping there might be some configuration stuff in jvm or tomcat to disable xml type data transfer between db rather use the objects( this is my guess, I really do not know how the data transfer between db and app server takes place).Though the xdb.jar is not there in my windows machine and it works fine. And even in few development server it works and there is no xdb.jar file